# How can I show an error Message if test fails?

Tags: java, junit

For Example I have this method:
Number.java

```
public static int add(int nr1, int nr2) {
        return nr2 + nr2;
    }
```

As you see I return number2 + number2

In my Test I use that it would throw the error that it was expected 9 instead of the number which was calculate in the main method.

```
 @Test
        public void test() throws Exception {
            int nr1 = 4;
            int nr2 = 5;
            int sum = Number.add(nr1, nr2);
            assertEquals(9, summe);
       }
```

I tried this to get an message if the program fails but it doesn´t work as I thought:

```
 @Test
        public void test() throws Exception {
            int nr1 = 4;
            int nr2 = 5;
            int sum = Number.add(nr1, nr2);
            assertEquals(9, sum);
            try {
                assertEquals(9, sum);
            }catch(AssertionError e) {
                String message = e.getMessage();
                message = "Did you calculate the right numbers together?";
            }
       }
```

Comment: what kind of message do you need? i mean a pop up message or what are actually  looking for ?

Comment: A Terminal message only. @daksh as I wrote the string message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `assertEquals(String message, int expected, int actual)` instead.

something like
`assertEquals("Did you calculate the right numbers together?", 9, sum)`

Source : [jUnit javadoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i've understood what you want but if i'm right you want assertEquals to give an error when the result is not right.
If it's it i think you need to edit the assertEquals function for throw and exception when the result is not right or return true if is correct and false if the result is wrong. When the assertEquals give the right result you can use it for display the message (if you want you can insert the message inside the throw exception)

Comment: Smile has answered the question for me I did not know that I can put a string in assertEquals();